# Web form application

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my web form, there's a white space on the right side, how to remove it or resize the panel?

I have tried `padding` and `margin` also `width` for panel and container but it's not working.

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 50px; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<div class="container"  >
  <div class="panel panel-primary" >
    <div class="panel-heading" >
      <h3 class="panel-title ">Personal Infomation</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body " >
      <br>
      <div id="p_info">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="first_name" >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" >
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="last_name" >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Gender</label>
            <select class="form-control field" id="sel1" >
              <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
              <option>Male</option>
              <option>Female</option>
            </select>
          </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="date" name="bdaytime" class="form-control" id="DOB"   >
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Place of Birth</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="Place" >
           </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to remove white space on this web from. why would this shows like that
let me know.I want to remove white space on this web from. why would this shows like that
let me know.I want to remove white space on this web from. why would this shows like that
let me know.
[I want to remove marked part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F7QT.png)

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap uses a media query for the *.col-md-6* class where it goes from full width to half width with a screen larger than 992px:

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

You can either create your own CSS rules or use an inline style (e.g., `<div class="col-md-6" style="width:100%">`) to override this Bootstrap style rule.

Comment: The media query may take precedence over an inline style since it may have greater specificity (I could not find documentation to confirm or deny this, but it may be the case). I would recommend adding a style tag *after* the stylesheet is linked that looks like this: `<style> @media (min-width: 992px) .col-md-6 { width: 100%; } </style>`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you look for ?

```css
.panel-body {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <style>
  .container {
    margin-top: 50px; 
  }


  </style>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="container"  >
  <div class="panel panel-primary" >
    <div class="panel-heading" >
      <h3 class="panel-title ">Personal Infomation</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body " >
      <br>
      <div id="p_info">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="first_name" >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" >
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="last_name" >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Gender</label>
            <select class="form-control field" id="sel1" >
              <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
              <option>Male</option>
              <option>Female</option>
            </select>
          </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="date" name="bdaytime" class="form-control" id="DOB"   >
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Place of Birth</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="Place" >
           </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 50px; 
}

.three-col {
width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<div class="container"  >
  <div class="panel panel-primary" >
    <div class="panel-heading" >
      <h3 class="panel-title ">Personal Information</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body " >
      <br>
      <div id="p_info">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="first_name" >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" >
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="last_name" >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row three-col">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <label class="control-label">Gender</label>
            <select class="form-control field" id="sel1" >
              <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
              <option>Male</option>
              <option>Female</option>
              <option>Other</option>
            </select>
          </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="row three-col">
           <div class="col-md-3">
            <label class="control-label">Date of Birth</label>
            <input type="date" name="bdaytime" class="form-control" id="DOB"   >
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="control-label">Place of Birth</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="Place" >
           </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please note: gender denotes identity and can have multiple values; sex can have three values (male, female, intersex).